# Cannot write on json file in express app nodejs

Tags: node.js, fs, writefile

I'm trying to read and write some data in express application (in a json file which already exists and has some data) using FS nodejs module but it returns this error in console:

Object { errno: -13, code: "EACCES", syscall: "open", path: "data.json" }

It works in localhost, but not on my web server and I don't understand where is the problem.

I've tried several ways to write on file and I'm sure this one works perfectly.

SERVER SIDE CODE:

```
app.post('/addLocation', function(req, res){
  var jsonFile = JSON.parse(fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname,'data.json'),'utf8'));
  jsonFile.locations.push(req.body); //json data is an array named 'locations'
  fileSystem.writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(jsonFile, null, 2), function(err){
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else res.send('SERVER MESSAGE: data saved');
  });
})
```

CLIENT SIDE CODE:

```
const data = {name, address, lat, lng, content, audience, detail, language, purpose, description};
  $.ajax({
     url: '/addLocation',
     type: "POST",
     data: data,
     success: function(result){
       console.log(result);
     }
  });
```

*ERROR in console*:

**Object { errno: -13, code: "EACCES", syscall: "open", path: "data.json" }**

Comment: `EACCES` > Permission denied. The user that you are using to start the app does not have the read (and / or write) access to the target file.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I only had read permission. Thank you!